# How to ignore CSS bottom property?

Tags: html, css

How can I ignore bottom property on mobile screens?

```
<div id="myID">...</div>
```

---

```
#myID {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (min-width:305px) and (max-width:415px) {
  #myID {
    top: 8px !important;
    right: 225px !important;
    zoom: 0.6 !important;
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
  }
}
```

It tries to take `bottom:5px` and `top:8px` at the same time, and it causes some problems on mobile screens.

Comment: But your code working fine without `bottom` property in given `media query` range.

Comment: It works fine on Chrome mobile device mode, however ıt doesn't work perfect on real mobile device when i scroll the page fast.

Comment: Once check the dimensions you used. Better to use the standard mobile sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) to the initial value `auto`, e.g.

```
@media (min-width:305px) and (max-width:415px) {
  bottom: auto;
  ...
}
```

By the way, you can remove all the `!important` declaration in your example. In fact it's highly recommended to do so, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3706819/483779) to learn more.